# Choosing an appropriate data structure for point-intersection detecting

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have some kind of shapes (rectangles, triangles, circles, etc.) that are given by points in space (coordinates). For example, for a rectangle - [0,0] and [5,5] - opposite corners.

There will be a lot of such shapes. My task is to find all shapes that contain a given point in themselves or on their edges.

Coordinates are always integers.

The total size of the coordinate plane can reach more than 2,000,000 x 2,000,000 points.

I'm trying to choose an appropriate data structure for this task. I was thinking about the Point Quadtree, and adding each point of the given shape to the tree. However, after thinking a little, I realized that if the maximum size of the shape is given, then I will end up with more than 2,000,000 x 2,000,000 nodes, which will be equivalent to a two-dimensional array with a size of 2,000,000 x 2,000,000. And that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Which data structure would suit me best?

Comment: How many points do you need to search? If it's just one, go through a vector of shapes and check if it's inside.

Comment: how many shapes you will have? and how many queries? The simple approach (keep a list of shapes and check the queries against every shape) is not enough?

Comment: Each shape has its own needs. Testing point intersection is simple for each one. Circles, for example, need only a center point and a radius. Etc. The size of the coordinate plane is irrelevant.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana 
There will be a method that takes a point as a parameter and will have to return a list of shapes. It will be called very often, so the "search" should be fast enough.

Comment: Ok, so your task is to solve **many** point in shape queries on a **fixed** set of shapes? Make the problem simpler by taking the oriented bounding box of each shape and use a data structure for rectangles.

Comment: @Federico There may be a lot of shapes (hundreds of thousands), as well as the count of queries. The linear solution is not enough.

Comment: This sounds like [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). I remember using and implementation for containing rectangles.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Write a [mcve] with lots of shapes, lots of queries, linear search through all of them, and timing. Then come back and ask how to make it faster.